# Porque o background-color só funciona com overflow:hidden?

Tags: css

Estou criando um menu e desejo colocar uma cor de fundo nele, no entanto, quando tento aplicar um `backgrond-color: #333` em um elemento `ul` **SEM** o `overflow: hidden;`, a cor não aparece.

Porque isso acontece se o `overflow` nada tem a ver com a cor de fundo? Para que realmente serve o `overflow`?

> CÓDIGO DO CSS:

```
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

> CÓDIGO DO HTML:

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Se puderem editem o título, por favor (não sei como esclarecer a dúvida no título).

Comment: Acho que o título está perfeito!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não é o overflow.

O problema é que sua ul não tem altura. Ela recebe a cor mas não dá para ver...

**Veja:**

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**> Overflow**

Se trata apenas da barra de rolagem.

Pelo que entendi, quando você colocou essa característica, você deu uma altura mínima para ul...

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o @DiegoSantos falou só de colocar uma altura já resolve, mas isso não explica porque com o `Overflow` funciona e sem não.

A explicação é que o `overflow` muda o contexto do elemento. Aqui vc pode ler sobre isso: https://makandracards.com/makandra/9245-use-overflow-hidden-to-avoid-floating-elements-from-wrapping-a-container-s-text

Inclusive a mesma técnica do `overflow` é usada para corrigir problemas da altura do Pai quando os Filhos tem algum `float` setado e o pai não tem altura.

Aqui tem a documentação da Mozilla que aborda o assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

> A block formatting context is created by at least one of the
>   following:
>
> - floats (elements where float is not none)
> - block elements where `overflow` has a value other than > visible

***No seu caso o seu `<li>` tem `float:left`***, se vc apenas tira-lo ou colocar     `display:inline-block` a cor do BG vai aparecer, pois o `<ul>` vai ganhar a altura do seu `<a>` que está com `display:block`.

Agora se quiser continuar usando o `float:left` o efeito que o `overflow:hidden` faz é com que a `<ul>` assuma a altura do filho que tenha `display:block` no caso o seu `<a>`. Tanto que com o `overflow:hidden` na `<ul>` qualquer valor de height, line-height, ou padding por exemplo que vc colocar no `<a>` vai se refletir na altura do pai o `<ul>`

Veja o exemplo no caso do `float`:

```css
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 200px;
}
div > div {
  float: left;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.over {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="over">
  <div>com overflow no pai</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div>sem overflow no pai</div>
</div>
```